# The past time scheduled buses cannot show

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm doing a bus reservation system. This is my bus schedule:

[image: structure of bus schedule]

Here you can see in the 1st row (route_id = 1) the departure time is 12.15 pm.  Now, In my website the 1st form is for selecting the place and the date of reservation. After selecting the date and the place the 2nd form will appear with available bus. This is my concept.

Now I’m selecting the ‘Colombo’ and ‘jaffna’ (1st row according to table) and the date is 2016-06-09. (today’s date: 2016-06-7 and when I’m selecting this, my time is 12.20 pm) in the 1st form.

In the 2nd form available bus is not appearing.

I have done a small validation which is:

(here $booked_date is the selecting date from the 1st form and $departure is the time of bus according to the table)

```
if ($booked_date >= date(“Y-m-d”) && ($departure > date('H:i:s'))) {
    // show the bus
}
```

My problem is if I select 2016-06-07 (today’s date and the time of selecting date is 12.20pm) the bus won’t show because the departure time is 12.15pm. The time has passed. So the bus won’t show.

But when I’m select 2016-06-09 (2 days’ form today’s date and the time of selecting date is 12.20pm) this bus has to show. but here it is not showing. How to set up this validation.

I do not want the past time scheduled buses. How to do that?

Comment: If the date is in the future, there's no need to compare the time with the current time. You should only compare the time when it's the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ImClarky pointed out that your logic is wrong. Better alternative is to compare the time in seconds like this:

```
$curTime = time();
$bookedTime = strtotime($booked_date.' '.$departure);
if($bookedTime > $curTime) {
   // show the bus
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current `if` is that, regardless of what `$booked_date` is, if `$departure` is before the current time it's not going to display the bus. You need to handle them separately. Something like this may work:

```
$curDate = date('Y-m-d');
if($booked_date > $curDate || ($booked_date == $curDate && $departure > date('H:i:s'))) {
    // show the bus
}
```